# Relationship between the Picard-Fuchs differential equation and the hypergeometric differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, hypergeometric-function, modular-function

Consider the Picard-Fuchs differential equation:
$$\frac{d^2 \Omega}{dJ^2} + \frac{1}{J} \frac{d\Omega}{dJ} + \frac{31J - 4}{144J^2 (1 - J)^2} \Omega = 0.$$
The author of this [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X03000428) claims that the solutions to this equation are those to the hypergeometric differential equation
$$J(1 - J) \frac{d^2 \Omega}{dJ^2} + [c - (a + b + 1)J] \frac{d\Omega}{dJ} - ab\Omega = 0$$
with $a = 11/12$, $b = 11/12$, $c = 4/3$, multiplied by $J^{1/6} (1 - J)^{3/4}$.

My question is: how does one know that? How can one look the Picard-Fuchs differential equation above and know that its solutions are related to the solutions of the hypergeometric differential equation? Is it because the Picard-Fuchs differential equation is related to Riemann's differential equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega=J^p(1-J)^qX$ ,

Then $\dfrac{d\Omega}{dJ}=J^p(1-J)^q\dfrac{dX}{dJ}+J^p(1-J)^q\left(\dfrac{p}{J}-\dfrac{q}{1-J}\right)X$

$\dfrac{d^2\Omega}{dJ^2}=J^p(1-J)^q\dfrac{d^2X}{dJ^2}+J^p(1-J)^q\left(\dfrac{p}{J}-\dfrac{q}{1-J}\right)\dfrac{dX}{dJ}+J^p(1-J)^q\left(\dfrac{p}{J}-\dfrac{q}{1-J}\right)\dfrac{dX}{dJ}+J^p(1-J)^q\left(\dfrac{p(p-1)}{J^2}-\dfrac{2pq}{J(1-J)}+\dfrac{q(q-1)}{(1-J)^2}\right)X=J^p(1-J)^q\dfrac{d^2X}{dJ^2}+2J^p(1-J)^q\left(\dfrac{p}{J}-\dfrac{q}{1-J}\right)\dfrac{dX}{dJ}+J^p(1-J)^q\left(\dfrac{p(p-1)}{J^2}-\dfrac{2pq}{J(1-J)}+\dfrac{q(q-1)}{(1-J)^2}\right)X$

$\therefore J^p(1-J)^q\dfrac{d^2X}{dJ^2}+2J^p(1-J)^q\left(\dfrac{p}{J}-\dfrac{q}{1-J}\right)\dfrac{dX}{dJ}+J^p(1-J)^q\left(\dfrac{p(p-1)}{J^2}-\dfrac{2pq}{J(1-J)}+\dfrac{q(q-1)}{(1-J)^2}\right)X+\dfrac{1}{J}\left(J^p(1-J)^q\dfrac{dX}{dJ}+J^p(1-J)^q\left(\dfrac{p}{J}-\dfrac{q}{1-J}\right)X\right)+\dfrac{31J-4}{144J^2(1-J)^2}J^p(1-J)^qX=0$

$\dfrac{d^2X}{dJ^2}+\left(\dfrac{2p}{J}-\dfrac{2q}{1-J}\right)\dfrac{dX}{dJ}+\left(\dfrac{p(p-1)}{J^2}-\dfrac{2pq}{J(1-J)}+\dfrac{q(q-1)}{(1-J)^2}\right)X+\dfrac{1}{J}\dfrac{dX}{dJ}+\left(\dfrac{p}{J^2}-\dfrac{q}{J(1-J)}\right)X-\left(\dfrac{1}{36J^2}-\dfrac{23}{144J}-\dfrac{23}{144(1-J)}-\dfrac{3}{16(1-J)^2}\right)X=0$

$\dfrac{d^2X}{dJ^2}+\left(\dfrac{2p+1}{J}-\dfrac{2q}{1-J}\right)\dfrac{dX}{dJ}+\left(\dfrac{p^2}{J^2}-\dfrac{(2p+1)q}{J(1-J)}+\dfrac{q(q-1)}{(1-J)^2}\right)X-\left(\dfrac{1}{36J^2}-\dfrac{23}{144J(1-J)}-\dfrac{3}{16(1-J)^2}\right)X=0$

$\dfrac{d^2X}{dJ^2}+\left(\dfrac{2p+1}{J}-\dfrac{2q}{1-J}\right)\dfrac{dX}{dJ}+\left(\dfrac{36p^2-1}{36J^2}-\dfrac{144(2p+1)q-23}{144J(1-J)}+\dfrac{16q(q-1)+3}{16(1-J)^2}\right)X=0$

Choose $p=\dfrac{1}{6}$ and $q=\dfrac{3}{4}$ , the ODE becomes

$\dfrac{d^2X}{dJ^2}+\left(\dfrac{4}{3J}-\dfrac{3}{2(1-J)}\right)\dfrac{dX}{dJ}-\dfrac{121}{144J(1-J)}X=0$

$J(1-J)\dfrac{d^2X}{dJ^2}+\left(\dfrac{4}{3}-\dfrac{17}{6}J\right)\dfrac{dX}{dJ}-\dfrac{121}{144}X=0$

Answer (score 2):

Those things are not really hard. All one has to do is to reduce the ODE to its normal form (meaning such where the coefficient at the 1st derivative equals zero)  and then compare the result to the normal form of an appropriately rescaled target ODE in this case the hypergeometric ODE. A generic ODE
\begin{equation}
y^{''}(x) + a_1(x) y^{'}(x)+a_2(x) y(x)=0
\end{equation}
is transformed to its normal form by writing $y(x)=\exp(-1/2 \int a_1(x) dx ) \cdot v(x)$. Then the function $v(x)$ satisfies the following ODE:
\begin{equation}
v^{''}(x) + Q_1(x) v(x)=0
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
Q_1(x):=\left( a_2(x)- \frac{1}{2} a_1^{'}(x) - \frac{1}{4} a_1(x)^2 \right) \quad (I)
\end{equation}

On the other hand if we take the hypergeometric ODE:
\begin{equation}
x(1-x)Y^{''}(x) + \left(c-(1+a+b) x \right) Y^{'}(x)- a b Y(x)=0
\end{equation}
and change the dependent variable $x \rightarrow f(x)$, $d/d x \rightarrow 1/f^{'}(x) d/d x$ and then reduce the result to the normal form then we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
V^{''}(x) +  Q_2(x) V(x)=0
\end{eqnarray}
where
\begin{eqnarray}
Q_2(x):= -\frac{N_2(x)}{4 (f(x)-1)^2 f(x)^2 f'(x)^2} \quad (II)
\end{eqnarray}
where 
\begin{eqnarray}
N_2(x):=f'(x)^4 \left(f(x) \left(-2 c (a+b-1)+\left((a-b)^2-1\right) f(x)+4 a b\right)+(c-2) c\right)+3 (f(x)-1)^2 f(x)^2 f''(x)^2-2 (f(x)-1)^2 f(x)^2 f^{(3)}(x) f'(x)
\end{eqnarray}
and $Y(f(x)) = (1-f(x))^{-(1+a+b-c)/2} \cdot f(x)^{-c/2} \cdot \sqrt{f^{'}(x)} \cdot V(x)$.

Now for a given $Q_1(x)$ all we need to do is to find a certain $f(x)$ and the appropriate parameters $a$,$b$ and $c$ such that $Q_2$ matches $Q_1$. It is not always possible but in this case as it turns out it is.

Now let us apply this algorithm to our case to demonstrate that it works. As usual it is a good idea to generalize the problem slightly. We take:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&a_1(x):= \frac{T_0}{x} \\
&&a_2(x):= \frac{T_1 x+T_2}{(x+x_0)^2 (x+x_1)^2}\\
\Longrightarrow&&\\
&&Q_1(x)= \frac{P_0 +P_1 x+P_2 x^2 + P_3 x^3 + P_4 x^4}{4 x^2 (x+x_0)^2 (x+x_1)^2}
\end{eqnarray}
where
\begin{eqnarray}
P_0&=&(2-T_0) T_0 x_0^2 x_1^2\\
P_1&=& 2(2-T_0)T_0 x_0 x_1(x_0+x_1)\\
P_2&=&4 T_2 + (2-T_0) T_0 (x_0^2+4 x_0 x_1 +x_1^2)\\
P_3&=&4 T_1 +2(2-T_0)T_0 (x_0+x_1)\\
P_4&=&(2-T_0) T_0
\end{eqnarray}

Now let's go back to our hypergeometric ODE . We take:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&f(x)= \frac{A x+B}{C x+D}\\
\Longrightarrow&&\\
&&Q_2(x)= \frac{(B C - A D)^2}{4} \cdot \frac{{\mathfrak P}_0 + {\mathfrak P}_1 x + {\mathfrak P}_2 x^2}{(A x+B)^2 (C x+D)^2 ((A-C) x+B-D)^2}
\end{eqnarray}
where
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak P}_0&=&B^2 \left(-\left((a-b)^2-1\right)\right)+2 B D (c (a+b-1)-2 a b)-(c-2) c D^2\\
{\mathfrak P}_1&=&2 \left(-A B \left((a-b)^2-1\right)+A D (c (a+b-1)-2 a b)+C (B c (a+b-1)-2 a b B-(c-2) c D)\right)\\
{\mathfrak P}_2&=&A^2 \left(-\left((a-b)^2-1\right)\right)+2 A C (c (a+b-1)-2 a b)-(c-2) c C^2
\end{eqnarray}

Now it is already at the first glimpse that we see that $Q_1$ does not match $Q_2$ in general. However if we take $x_0=0$ (as it is in the very question above) then those quantities may match.

Indeed we choose $C=A$,$B=0$ and $D=A x_1$ which makes the denominators of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ match. The remaining thing is to match the numerators by solving a system of three coupled quadratic equations for the parameters of the hypergeometric function $a$,$b$ and $c$. It turns out that there are eight set of solutions. One of those solutions reads:
\begin{eqnarray}
y(x)&=& x^{\frac{c-T_0}{2}}\cdot \left(x+x_1\right)^{1-(1+a+b)/2} F_{2,1}\left[ a,b,c; \frac{x}{x+x_1}\right]
\end{eqnarray}
where
\begin{eqnarray}
a&=&-\frac{(-2+T_0) x_1 + \delta_1+\delta_2}{2 x_1}\\
b&=&-\frac{(-2+T_0) x_1 + \delta_1-\delta_2}{2 x_1}\\
c&=&1-\frac{\delta_1}{x_1}
\end{eqnarray}
where 
\begin{eqnarray}
\delta_1&=& \sqrt{-4 T_2+(-1+T_0)^2 x_1^2}\\
\delta_2&=& \sqrt{-4 T_2 + x_1(4 T_1+x_1)}
\end{eqnarray}

See the code below to make sure that it is correct:

```
In[736]:= T0 =.; T1 =.; T2 =.; x1 =.; a =.; b =.; c =.; x =.;
{dlt1, dlt2} = {Sqrt[-4 T2 + (-1 + T0)^2 x1^2], 
   Sqrt[(-4 T2 + x1 (4 T1 + x1))]};
{a, b, c} = {-(((-2 + T0) x1 + dlt1 + dlt2)/(
    2 x1^1)), -(((-2 + T0) x1^1 + dlt1 - dlt2)/(2 x1^1)), 
   1 - dlt1/x1^1};
eXX = (D[#, {x, 2}] + 
      T0/x D[#, 
        x] + (T1 x + T2)/(x^2 (x + x1)^2) #) & /@ {Hypergeometric2F1[
      a, b, c, x/(x + x1)] (x)^(
     c/2 - T0/2) (x + x1)^(-(1/2) (1 + a + b) + 1)};

{T0, T1, T2, x1, x} = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
eXX

T0 =.; T1 =.; T2 =.; x1 =.; a =.; b =.; c =.; x =.;
{a, b, c} = {(T0 x1^1 - dlt2 + dlt1)/(2 x1^1), (
   T0 x1^1 + dlt1 + dlt2)/(2 x1^1), 1 + dlt1/x1^1};
eXX = (D[#, {x, 2}] + 
      T0/x D[#, 
        x] + (T1 x + T2)/(x^2 (x + x1)^2) #) & /@ {Hypergeometric2F1[
      a, b, c, x/(x + x1)] (x)^(
     c/2 - T0/2) (x + x1)^(-(1/2) (1 + a + b) + 1)};

{T0, T1, T2, x1, x} = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
eXX



Out[741]= {0.*10^-44 + 0.*10^-44 I}

Out[746]= {0.*10^-47 + 0.*10^-47 I}
```